# Read and write to the same csv file - delete row if condition met (stop writerow to erase everything in file)

Tags: python, file, csv, syntax

I am trying to create an archive to store a list of available books in the system. I want my program to ask the user to input csv file, read a list of books from that file, check the year of publication and delete the row if the book is older than 7 years. 
I want to keep everything in a single file.

So far, instead of deleting certain rows, writerow deletes everything in the file. Could someone help me to understand how to fix it?

```
import csv
import os
import time

archive = os.listdir()


def get_user_files(self):
    while True:
        for position, file_name in enumerate(archive):
            print(position, "-", file_name)
        userInput = input("\n\n ")
        if (int(userInput) < 0) or (int(userInput) > len(archive)):
            print("Invalid Input. Try again. \n")
        else:
            print("Loading succesful!")
            break

    global cvs_list
    cvs_list = archive[int(userInput)]  # Store file
    archive.remove(cvs_list)  # Remove from the list


    with open(cvs_list, 'r') as in_file, open(cvs_list, 'w') as out_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file)
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        for row in reader:
            next(reader) #skip headers
            if int(row[2]) < 2011:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Edit:

```
with open(cvs_list, 'r') as in_file:
        csv_in = csv.reader(in_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        filtered_list = []
        row1 = next(csv_in)
        filtered_list.append(row1)
        for row in csv_in:
            if int(row[2]) >= 2011: 
                row.append(filtered_list)

        with open(cvs_list, 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerows(filtered_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

def filter_dates(csv_filepath)
    with open(csv_filepath, 'r') as in_file:
        csv_in = list(csv.reader(in_file))
    # create accumulator for new list to add only valid values
    filtered_list = []
    filetered_list.append(csv_in[0]) # append header to new list
    # filter the list making sure no errors appear BEFORE writing to the file
    for row in csv_in[1:]: #skip header (first row)
        if int(row[2]) >= 2011: # if entry is NEWER OR EQUAL TO than 7 years, we add it to filtered_list
            filtered_list.append(row)
    # now filtered_list contains only entires where index position 2 contains valid years
    with open(csv_filepath, 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows
```

Here is a fully independent example:

```
 csv_in = [
    ['name', 'sbin', 'year'],
    ['moby_dick', 'sbin', '1851'],
    ['new_book', 'sbin', '2011'],
    ['newest_book', 'sbin', '2018'],

]
filtered_list = []
filtered_list.append(csv_in[0]) # this is where the header is added
for row in csv_in[1:]: #skip header (first row)
    if int(row[2]) >= 2011:
        filtered_list.append(row)
print(filtered_list)
```

A couple of notes:

- it's generally good to store this kind of stuff in memory *before* you open the file to write (or overwrite in this case) so that any error while reading and filtering the file happens before we try to modify the output
- easiest way to overwrite a file is to first read it, commit the contents to memory (`csv_in` the array I've defined in the first `with` block this case), and then *finally8 once the data is ready (`filtered_list`) for 'shipping' commit it to a file
- never **ever** use the `global` declaration in python, it's never worth it and causes a lot of headaches down the line

test

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, I can't make your code work for me. I tried to adjust the code, but I keep getting errors. The first error I get was 'local variable 'row' referenced before assignment'. Next error that occurs is 

for row in csv_in[1:]:
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

I have changed the code a bit and currently, it saves the headers but no other values are saved into the new file. Could you please guide me how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I had a typo, it should be `filtered_list.append(row)`

Comment: @MagicCat I have also added an independent example, this should be a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not advised to read and write to the same open file handle for reasons like this. Instead, read the entire file to a data structure, and in a separate `with` block, write your new data. This also makes it easier to write to a different file (perhaps with a timestamp attached), which can be handy when you (like everyone) inevitably screw something up and need to try your new code on your old data- you have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
with open(cvs_list, 'r') as in_file:
        csv_in = csv.reader(in_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        filtered_list = []
        row1 = next(csv_in)
        filtered_list.append(row1)
        for row in csv_in:
            if int(row[2]) >= 2011: 
                row.append(filtered_list)
        # WRONG! you are opening the same file for output 
        # in the upper block
        with open(cvs_list, 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerows(filtered_list)
```

It is *far better* to read and write at the same time then copy the tmp file onto the source.

Like this:

```
#  NOT TESTED!
with open(cvs_list, 'r') as in_file, open(tmp_file, 'w') as out_file:
    csv_in = csv.reader(in_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(next(csv_in))
    writer.writerows(row for row in csv_in if int(row[2])>=2011)
```

Then at the end of that `with` block you can copy the temp file on top of the source file:

```
from shutil import move
move(tmp_file, cvs_list)
```